# simple adapter issue for multiple words String in android

Tags: android

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                ParseXMLDemo.this.adapter1.getFilter().filter(cs.toString().trim());   

                if(list2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
                    list2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
                if(inputSearch.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    list2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    list2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {

                  }
              @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
```

if inputSearch = "India Gate"
after India the later word after space shows but if i type G after space the reult hides automatically.

Comment: Please move this list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2); line onCreate().

Comment: Same reult like previous one after space if I type some thing the search result hides automatically.@ Haresh Chhelana

Comment: can you please post filter code ?

Comment: adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.list_layout2, 
                new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_CITY,KEY_COUNT}, 
                new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.subtitle,R.id.subtitle2}); This is my adapter.I called it at  onTextChanged method.@Haresh Chhelana

Comment: i think i ask for filter code not for adapter.

Comment: Here I don't use another custom filter code.If u know any filter code please post here.I am totally new in android development.@Haresh Chhelana

Comment: Check my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236319/on-search-getting-array-out-of-index-bound-exception/25236590#25236590 and try to implement this way on you project.

Comment: it is not exact requreiment of my apps.

Comment: ParseXMLDemo.this.adapter1.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());   Log.d("Spacing",cs.toString()); in case of log message able to see all characters what i typed but at list view only see the characters before the space, whenever provide a space the results hide automatically.